# ObjectiveC-NSMutable array specific indexes stored in another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, nsmutablearray

Is there anyway I can add specific objects in NSMutableArray to another array in objective c? I can accomplish that in Java but cannot figure it our for objective c

For example I have an array of 7 strings and I only want indexes 1, 3 ,7 stored in another array.

Comment: To be clear; you want the array index stored in this other array, not the string objects?

Comment: @Droppy no sorry I meant the strings in these indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of creating the array from the string values at particular indexes:

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;    // Array with strings
NSArray *someOtherArray = @[ array[1], array[3], array[7] ];
```

So both `array[1]` and `someOtherArray[0]` point to the same (`NSString`) instance, etc.

Comment: THANKS that helped..will accept  the answer in 2 min :D

Answer (score 0):

This is what NSIndexSet (and NSMutableIndexSet) is for.

You can build it manually or use helper methods on NSArray like:

```
indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
```

to build an index set from a block.  You can then enumerate over the NSIndexSet using a for loop - using the index to call into the original array.